# mysql create table help with unique

Tags: mysql, unique, create-table

I'm trying to create a table, and can't figure out how to assign two columns to be unique.. I know how to alter a table thats already created, but how do you do it in the create..

im after a create if not exist col1 TEXT, col2 TEXT, col3 TEXT unique(col1, col2)

^very rough basic but you get the idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put that the end of your table, put a comma after your last TEXT

```
UNIQUE (
`temp`
)
```